# Display Update Timestamp in Java

Tags: java, timestamp

I have a general question about Java.  When one issues a command to display something, is there any way to get the actual time at which the display was updated?  Suppose I issued a display command at the end of a refresh cycle on a 60 Hz monitor (say at time = t ms), it will take another 16.67 ms for the display to be updated with the new information - right?  So the actual time at which the display is updated is (t + 16.67) ms.  Can this information be retrieved from any of the Java class attributes/methods?

Thanks,
Zhivago...

Comment: Sounds very platform-specific. No such function in Java itself, if you are lucky, there may be a native call you can access from Java.

Comment: I was thinking that this should be analogous to getting the time at which a keypress happened.  I have come across this psychWithJava class that is able to do that.  Guess it may be just polling for a keypress and returns the time at which something comes into the keyboard buffer.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Measuring user response time? If so (and it matters at all) maybe just subtract 1/60 s from their response time to account for display latency?

Comment: Yeah I''m trying to see how accurate an estimate of user response time can be obtained if I used Java.  But 1/60 s will be the worst case latency, right?  So the measurement of response time will have an error in the range 0 to 1/60 s.  Guess there's no other way to reduce this error.

Comment: Is the screen refresh rate an important error factor? How big are these response times?

Comment: Anywhere from 300 to 2000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably do this with a monitoring thread that fired at set intervals, but you would have the issue of mistiming due to thread starvation, resource locking, and other concurrency issues.

investigate java.lang.Thread and java.util.Timer

Comment: Yeah that wouldn't be worth it I guess. Thanks.